# Any way of updating all links in spry menu bar in all pages?

Tags: menu, hyperlink, dreamweaver, spry

I am currently designing an e-learning course for a college project. I am using a horizontal spry menu bar. I only have all updated links to other pages on the homepage. All of the rest are empty. I will finish up having more than 140 pages so is there anyway I can update the links from the homepage to work on all pages?

It would save me a huge amount of time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways.

The first, and best, way is to call the menu code as some form of include on all pages of your site.  You can put the ul structure of the menu system in a separate HTML file and use SSI or any server side language to call it as an include.  If you don't have any access to SSI or a server side language, you can make the menu code a Dreamweaver Library Item and call it that way.  The benefit here is the menu code exists in one place.  Any update to the code will update throughout the site.

The second way is to use Dreamweaver's site-wide find and replace feature to make changes to the menu code on every page of your site.

Comment: Could you explain how i use the find and replace feature to update the links on all pages for me please. Sorry but I am very new to Dreamweaver. I have 128 pages to do, I updated 10 there and it took me almost 2 hours....

Comment: Thanks. Im sorry but I am very new to Dreamweaver and how it all works. Is there any way you could dumb down what you said for me? It appears that a lot of people have trouble with this but in any of the answers to this question they go off talking about code and ssi and im familiar with neither.

Comment: Find and Replace is simply found under the Edit Menu.  Click it and you will see what I'm talking about.  You would choose "Source Code" and "Entire Local Site" for the scope and just enter the code to find and the code to replace.

Comment: For the include solution, I suggest you use Library Items if the mention of SSI or server-side scripting is confusing to you.  Library Items are built into Dreamweaver and have help entries: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/dreamweaver/cs/using/WSc78c5058ca073340dcda9110b1f693f21-7e49a.html